# origin must be supplied when using bacon decomposition

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I'm trying to do a difference-in-difference regression with multiple time periods. The bacon function is supposed to make the decomposition of the time but I get "Error in as.Date.numeric(value): 'origin' must be supplied" and I am not sure where I am supposed to add the origin

```
library(bacondecomp)
m1<-bacon(mort~treatment,data,id_var="state",time_var ="date")
```

There are 32 states in total and for each state, I have 131 observations trough time. My df looks like this :

```
data<-sample_n(data, 20)
dput(data)
```

structure(list(state = c("SAN LUIS POTOSI", "JALISCO", "SONORA",
"MORELOS", "CAMPECHE", "CAMPECHE", "OAXACA", "QUERETARO", "AGUASCALIENTES",
"DURANGO", "DURANGO", "CHIAPAS", "SAN LUIS POTOSI", "JALISCO",
"DISTRITO FEDERAL", "MEXICO", "SINALOA", "TABASCO", "MEXICO",
"VERACRUZ"), date = structure(c(18377, 18395, 18521, 18283, 18351,
18487, 18312, 18459, 18419, 18369, 18449, 18401, 18414, 18336,
18295, 18357, 18350, 18551, 18538, 18570), class = "Date"), treatment = c("0",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), mort = c(0, 0.00356731214801777,
0.00975690667030924, 0, 0, 0.0699568366317982, 0, 0.0307066432067913,
0.0348520703872414, 0, 0.0214018649585125, 0.019195978198255,
0.0209340639786863, 0, 0, 0.00344277731140896, 0.00316789126783444,
0.0194379554069977, 0.0223780525241583, 0.00585489554749245)), row.names = c(NA,
-20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you post your data `dput(data)` or a sample of it?

Comment: @markhogue yes! I already added it to my question

Comment: The help file for `bacon` says that the treatment variable has to be binary. Not sure what that means, but I tried running the sample data with treatment converted to numeric, but got the result  `Error in bacon(mort ~ treatment, data, id_var = "state", time_var = "date") : 
  Unbalanced Panel` Also tried with treatment converted to logical. There is only one positive treatment case, so maybe the problem is that there's no trend to discern from the data.

Comment: You might try with your full data set updated with `data$treatment <- as.numeric(data$treatment)`. Please let us know if this helped.